# Simply calculate $\frac{ \frac{65536!}{(65536 - 100)! }}{65536^{100}}$

Tags: permutations, exponentiation

I want to calculate this value exactly: $C=\frac{ \frac{65536!}{(65536 - 100)! }}{65536^{100}}$. Or at least I want to obtain an a convincing lower bound to argue that this value is close to 1.

It can be easily seen that the numerator is a permutation value, aka $P^{65536}_{100}$, also note that $65536=2^{16}$, if this may help you simplfy the expression.

One can simply lower bound this value $C\geq \frac{ (65536-99)^{99} }{65536^{99}} \approx 86\% $. Could anyone offer me a tigher bound? Or, if you can do the best, obtain the exact value? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sterling's approximation?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Divide%5BDivide%5B65536%21%2C%5C%2840%2965536-100%5C%2841%29%21%5D%2CPower%5B65536%2C100%5D%5D

Comment: The value is $$0.927215509481\cdots$$

Comment: @Peter How did you manage to get this value?

Comment: With PARI/GP , a tool for large numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the more general case of
$$A=\frac{\frac{a!}{(a-b)!} }{a^b}$$ Take logatihms and use Stirling approximation for large $a$.

You should obtain
$$\log(A)=-\frac{(b-1) b}{2 a}-\frac{(b-1) b (2 b-1)}{12
   a^2}-\frac{(b-1)^2 b^2}{12
   a^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{a^4}\right)$$

Using your numbers and my phone
$$\log\Bigg(\frac{ \frac{65536!}{(65536 - 100)! }}{65536^{100}}\Bigg)=-\frac{5317713913875}{70368744177664}$$

$$\frac{30}{397}<\frac{5317713913875}{70368744177664} <\frac{73}{966}$$ giving
$$ 0.92721542<A<0.92721784$$

Answer (score 1):

Let’s be brave and expand the numerator as shown below.
$$C=\dfrac{\dfrac{65536!}{(65536 - 100)! }}{65536^{100}}=\dfrac{\dfrac{65536\times 65535\times\dots\times  65437\times 65436\times \dots\times 2\times 1}{65436\times 65435\times 65434\times\dots\times 2\times 1}}{65536^{100}}$$

When we simplify the above expression on the right hand side, we get,
$$C=\dfrac{65536\times 65535\times\dots\times 65438\times 65437}{65536^{100}}.$$

Note that the numerator and denominator on the right hand side has equal number of multiplicands. Therefore, we shall write,
$$C=1\times\dfrac{65535}{65536}\times\dfrac{65534}{65536}\times\dots\times\dfrac{65438}{65536}\times\dfrac{65437}{65536}.$$

This can be written as,
$$C=\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2^{16}}\right)\times\left(1-\dfrac{2}{2^{16}}\right)\times\dots\times\left(1-\dfrac{50}{2^{16}}\right)\times\dots\times\left(1-\dfrac{98}{2^{16}}\right)\times\left(1-\dfrac{99}{2^{16}}\right).$$

Now, we are in a position to use a trick to further simplify the expression on the right hand side. Let’s take the first and the last multiplicands.
$$\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2^{16}}\right)\times\left(1-\dfrac{99}{2^{16}}\right)=1+\dfrac{99}{2^{32}}-\dfrac{100}{2^{16}}$$

The multiplication between the second and the penultimate multiplicands gives,
$$\left(1-\dfrac{2}{2^{16}}\right)\times\left(1-\dfrac{98}{2^{16}}\right)=1+\dfrac{196}{2^{32}}-\dfrac{100}{2^{16}}.$$

There are 49 such multiplications and the $49^{\text{th}}$ multiplication gives,
$$\left(1-\dfrac{2}{49^{16}}\right)\times\left(1-\dfrac{51}{2^{16}}\right)=1+\dfrac{2499}{2^{32}}-\dfrac{100}{2^{16}}.$$

Therefore, we can write down the expresssion for $C$ in the following form.
$$C=\left(1+\dfrac{99}{2^{32}}-\dfrac{100}{2^{16}}\right)\times\left(1+\dfrac{196}{2^{32}}-\dfrac{100}{2^{16}}\right)\times\dots\times\left(1+\dfrac{2499}{2^{32}}-\dfrac{100}{2^{16}}\right)\times\left(1-\dfrac{50}{2^{16}}\right)$$

Now we can determine the upper and the lower bounds of the given expression.
$$\left(1+\dfrac{2499}{2^{32}}-\dfrac{100}{2^{16}}\right)^{49}\times\left(1-\dfrac{50}{2^{16}}\right)\gt C\gt\left(1+\dfrac{99}{2^{32}}-\dfrac{100}{2^{16}}\right)^{49}\times\left(1-\dfrac{50}{2^{16}}\right)$$

When the two bounds are simplified, this looks like,
$$\small{0.927224239379141704120285686818\gt\dfrac{\dfrac{65536!}{(65536 - 100)! }}{65536^{100}}\gt0.9271988127178732384044710631461}.$$